# How can I see the list of all commits that affect a specific file with git (including orphaned or dangling commits)

Tags: git

I am using Git + Gerrit, and it is turning out to be a little more effort than I had anticipated.

As a consequence of not yet having reached the top of the learning curve; I have lost some changes that I made to a file.

I think that those changes might be in a previous commit that has somehow become orphaned in the merge-and-rebase song-and-dance routine that Gerrit seems to require.

How can I see the list of all commits (orphaned or not) that affect a particular file, so I can go through them one-by-one and try to find my changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about Gerrit and "merge-and-rebase song-and-dance" parts, but in Git you can always revert back once you committed (unless you take special actions to prevent this).

First of all check what commit you're interested in:

```
git reflog -- <file>
```

Once your (poor) orphaned commit's ID is known, you can do one of the following:

```
git merge <commit_id>
```

or

```
git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

The choice between the two is up to you and is dependent upon the following factors (among others):

- The state of your local copy
- Relative position (in the history) of the commit you're trying to recover
- How much time you have

EDIT:

Found an interesting trick:

```
git cherry-pick -n <commit_id>
```

this will aplly your orphaned commit over your current HEAD, but will not automatically commit the changes - you can checkout irrelevant stuff and keep only changes to the file in question.

Note: I never used rebase, therefore it may be the case that this trick need some kind of adaptation to your case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `log` to get the list of commits.  Doing this will show changes to file1 on all branches (see manpage for `git-log` for more information):

```
git log -g --pretty=oneline --all -- file1
```